# Generalization of the integral test for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, reference-request, improper-integrals

I'm looking for literature results on generalizations of the integral test for convergence.

In the classic integral test for convergence you get under certain conditions convergens of
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$$
if the integral
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)dx$$
is finite.

What I am looking for are higher dimensional analogs. So I have a lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ (take for example $L=\mathbb Z^n$) and want to check convergence of
$$\sum_{x \in L} f(x).$$
What I can show is that the integral
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x)dx$$
is finite.

I'm looking for all results and theorems in that direction and am very grateful for good references. Quite a few times I have seen such arguments where it isn't made precise. For example I've read "the sum behaves like the integral" without any further proof or argument.

I want to have clear conditions on how $f$ has to be that such arguments work.

In the context where I want to use the result the function $f$ is made up using a quadratic form of mixed signiture in the space $\mathbb R^n$ (for example signiture $(2,2)$ in $\mathbb R^4$). This results to some singularities of $f$, but the lattice $L$ is carefully chosen so that on the points $f(x)$ with $x \in L$ you would have no singularities (apart from $x=0$ but you can exclude that point in the sum). But still in my context the integral over $\mathbb R^n$ is finite.

**Example:**

Since you asked for examples in the comments here is one example I'm interested in:

Let $f : \mathbb R^4 \to \mathbb R$ be
$$f(x)= E_1(2(x_1^2+x_2^2))\exp(x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2).$$
Here $E_1$ is the exponential integral
$$E_1(x):=\int_1^\infty \exp(-tx) \frac{dt}{t}.$$
The function $f$ has singularities along the 2-dim subspace $(x_1,x_2)=(0,0)$. So choose the lattice $L \subseteq \mathbb R^4$ arbitrary such that it intersects trivially with the singularity plane.

I computed
$$\int_{\mathbb R^4} f(x)dx = \pi^2 \ln(2),$$
so the integral is finite. What about the sum
$$\sum_{x \in L\setminus\{0\}} f(x)?$$

Comment: The usual integral test imposes monotonicity on $f$ to prove by comparing area, which can be intuitively generalized to tests for multivariable functions, i.e. imposing component-wise monotonicity. However, the function you want to apply such a test is probably not monotonic since you say that it has singularities.

Comment: The standard integral test concerns a positive decreasing function $\to 0.$ So it's all about absolute convergence. It would be good to have a few examples in the multidimensional setting.

Comment: @zhw. I just added an example. If you could solve my question for that example I would already be quite happy even though I'm looking for a more general answer since I have more use for that principal than only that example.

Comment: Looks like your function is monotone on $(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 1})^4$, so I guess you just need to have a straightforward generalisation of integral test for mutivariable functions.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen But the lattice I take it not $\mathbb Z^4$.

Comment: ah right, my bad. Lemma delete my comment.

Comment: @ParesseuxNguyen You can delete it. Would be kind if you can provide a different argument for the convergence or divergence of my series ;-)